# Navigator.SceneConfigs can't find variable: Navigator

Tags: react-native

I want to configure various scene animations with Navigator.SceneConfigs ("FloatFromRight" and "FloatFromLeft").

Within the Scene - if I call the scene with a configured animation I receive the error message "Can't find variable: Navigator" (although I am of the opinion that I copied the code above from the React-Native examples).

```
_onPressBar1: function(){
    debugger;
    this.props.nav.push({
      id: 'Login',
      sceneConfig: Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromLeft,
    });
  },
```

I created the following Navigator:

```
render: function() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        style={styles.container}  
        renderScene ={this.renderScene}
        configureScene={(route) => {
          if (route.sceneConfig) {
            return route.sceneConfig;
          }
          return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
        }}
        initialRoute={{
          id: 'Login',
          index: 0,
        }} />
    );
  }
```

with the following renderScene:

```
renderScene: function(route, navigator){
    if ('Login' === route.id) {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <TopBar nav={navigator} displBackIcon={false} />
        <Login
          name={route.name}
          navigator={navigator} />
        <BottomBar nav={navigator} currentPage={route.id} />
      </View>
      );
    } else if ('Test' === route.id) {
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <TopBar nav={navigator} displBackIcon={false} />
          <Test
              navigator={navigator} />
          <BottomBar nav={navigator} currentPage={route.id} />
        </View>
      );
    } 
  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The _onPressBar1 function was included in a different file where I forgot to include the Navigator in the React definition:
`var {
  Image,
  Navigator,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} = React;`